# How to modify this Json Output in PHP?

Tags: php, json

Bellow are Dynamic Output for E-ticket

```
{
   charting: "CNP"
}
```

**To - chart not prepared**

```
{
    charting: "CP"
}
```

**To - chart prepared**

How to change this output in `PHP`

Thanks

Comment: can you add more details that how do you get this output and what is the source, what you have tried

Comment: I use third party API and its showing this status for chart prepared or not with only "CNP" and "CP" I need to convert both in full text like -  chart not prepared and chart prepared version

Comment: Can you add the code from where you got those responses?

Comment: Sorry I can't :( 
That not public API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json_decode()` to get the data, change the data as you need, and use `json_encode()` to encode it again.

e.g

```
<?php
$json = '{
   "charting": "CNP"
}';
$phpArray = json_decode($json, true);


if($phpArray['charting'] == 'CP'){
    $phpArray['charting'] = 'chart prepared';
}else if($phpArray['charting'] == 'CNP'){
    $phpArray['charting'] = 'chart not prepared';
}


echo json_encode($phpArray);
?>
```

Comment: This both values are not same every time so how could I encode it?

Comment: I edited my post @OliviaNielsen, is it what you are looking for?

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider marking your question as solved if everything works fine for you!